# Suggest any CSV editor plugin inside Eclipse to add new columns hustle free [between 2 of the existing columns]

Tags: csv, eclipse-plugin, text-editor

I am using existing CSV editor available in eclipse, but which is adding new columns only at the end. If I want to  add a new columns in the middle of existing columns, I need to edit in CSV source format type i.e. with comma separate format and feed all the data, which is very difficult.

[image: Existing eclipse CSV editor snap]

[image: CSV source mode]

Comment: Eclipse has no CSV editor built in. If the CSV editor plugin you use is open source and this feature does not exist, why don't you contribute it? I guess you talk about [CSV Edit Resurrector](https://github.com/Mathieuu/CsvEdit).

Answer (score 0):

I found one good utility tool. CSV pad.
Download this , it is helping me to add columns where ever i want, not only at the last.

Open the desired file from the location , then edit as you want, save it.
It wont effect the format. [you can direct open eclipse workspace testdata folder too from this tool and edit the input csv file].

https://www.trustfm.net/software/utilities/CSVpad.php
try good site to download this.

[CSVpad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0it7.png)

[Add columns anywhere you want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1ukz.png)